# How to handle relative routing in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am new to MVC and I have one particular route in my system which is default:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Employee", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Now, since it is defaulting to Employee/Index, both localhost:// and localhost://Employee/Index are going to the same default page location. So far so good. Now,

I have some methods which are calling  partial views on the fly with some KendoUI Tab Control click and the code looks like following:

```
tabstrip.Add()
  .Text("Details")
  .Selected(true)
  .LoadContentFrom("Employee/ShowEmployeeProfileInfo/" + @Model);
```

It works fine as far as I am on Localhost://. However, it does not work when I am on localhost/Employee/Index because it tries to browse to locahost/employee/Employee/ShowEmployeeProfileInfo(Noticed two "Employee(s) in the route?")

I think there is something wrong in the way I have configured the path or may be the way I am browsing to it. Any ideas?

Comment: It needs to be `"/Employee/ShowEmployeeProfileInfo .."` (leading `/`). You should always generate you urls using `@Url.Action("ShowEmployeeProfileInfo", "Employee")`. And note if your model is a complex object, there is a good chance using `@Model` will fail (pass an ID to the method)

Comment: From what I can see, you can use `.LoadContentFrom()` just like you do in for helpers in MVC by specifying the Action and controller, like this: `.LoadContentFrom("ShowEmployeeProfileInfo", "Employee")`

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Can you please turn this into answer so that I can mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your missing the leading forward slash. It needs to be `"/Employee/ShowEmployeeProfileInfo...`, however it is recommended to use `@Url.Action()` to generate you links

```
.LoadContentFrom('@Url.Action("ShowEmployeeProfileInfo", "Employee", new { id = Model })');
```